# How to fetch changes from a remote repository

Tags: git

I changed the namespace of my remote repository.
How can I update my local repository? so I can commit and push.

Comment: Have you tried `git pull`? Did you `git remote add origin yourRemoteRepo` (origin is just a name)

Comment: do you mean pull? or fetch? you can google both terms , `git pull` & `git fetch`

Comment: What do you mean with 'namespace' ?

Comment: Thanks for the help and reply. I got the answer from einverne ^_^ and it is now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `git remote -v` to check your remote repository. If you want to change your remote repository you can use `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git`. After you setup your remote repository you can `git pull` to update your local repository.

Check this article : http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-5.html

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you! ^_^ sorry for being a noob ='(

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add the new remote if you havent done it so far:
   `git remote add new_name new_url`

   2. Update the content of your repo with the new content from the new remote
      `git fetch --all --prune`
   3. If your branch is not checked out yet - checkout the desired branch.
   4. If your branch already checked out simply update it with `git pull new_name branch_name`

Comment: Thanks for the help and reply. I got the answer from einverne ^_^ and it is now working.